# Routing table where do packets go

Tags: ip, routing

(I hope this is the right place to ask questions like this and I apologise if it's not) This might be a dumb question but I'm having a little trouble understanding how routing tables work.

I have a practice table with addresses like this:

[image: Image of table]

And one question asks:

> Where will a packet destined to address
>   10.14.1.105 be sent?

The answer is:

> 10.14.1.254 via port 1

I don't really understand the answer as the address is not directly in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look at the Netmask of the address. This identifies the network portion of the IP address.

Since your routing table has **10.14.0.0** with a netmask of **255.255.0.0**, the network is **10.14.x.x** because it most closely matches it. Hosts on that network are anything from 10.14.0.1 - 10.14.255.254. Since you're looking at a host of 10.14.1.254, this aligns with the 10.14.0.0 network, therefore will forward the packet to the Next-hop (router) address 10.14.1.254 on interface 1.

The networks 10.0.0.0 with netmask of 255.0.0.0 and 0.0.0.0 with netmask 0.0.0.0 are also matches, but since there is an entry that more specifically defines the network in the table, it is selected. If the 10.14.0.0 entry didn't exist, the 10.0.0.0 route would be selected instead, followed by 0.0.0.0.

Metrics are used in case of conflict, so if two entries overlap, the one with the lowest metric (or cost) will have precedence over one with a higher metric. If the network 10.0.0.0 were set with a lower metric than 10.14.0.0, it could be selected instead.

The 0.0.0.0 / 0.0.0.0 network is a special entry called the gateway of last resort. If no matches are found in the table, the packet is forwarded there.

Comment: It might be noteworthy that it’s a “longest prefix” (AKA most specific) match. That’s also why “10.1.1.254” and “10.3.1.2” are *not* used.

Comment: Good point @DanielB. I edited my answer with that additional reason after I re-read it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand more clearly now but there is just one thing I don't understand. Another question ask "Where will a packet destined to address 193.218.1.1 be sent?", the answer is 10.3.1.2 via interface 1. I understand the addresses and why it takes 10.3.1.2, what I don't understand is why is the  "via interface 1" and  "via port 1".

Comment: Using the table in the original question, I would have to say it chooses the default route (0.0.0.0/0) and uses interface 4.